# How to set header titles to wrap in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt to display a bunch of information in a table.  I have a QTableWidget object and some of the header titles I want to include are longer than what I want the cell sizes to be.  For example, I would like to have

```
<html> <br>Acceleration <br> (m/s^2) </html>
```

instead of having both on the same line.  I know there is a word wrap capability in the cells, but I would like to keep the titles in the header so they can be distinguished more easily.  HTML in the strings doesn't seem to work in the header either so I can't use a `<br>`. Is there a way to get text to wrap, or manually break lines within the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple `\n` to manually break your header title:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTableWidget w(2, 2);
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "FOO\nBAR" << "FOOBAR");
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't even think to try that, thanks!

Comment: Not really a good solution if your columns are dynamic, and you  want auto word wrapping.