# Wrap header titles in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableView with a QHeaderView set.

I would like to set wordwrap on the header content (QString), but not the table content. Is this possible?

It is dynamic data, so I am not able to use \n in my strings.
The columns of my list have a fixed width.

I don't see any wordwrap for this object any where here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html

I see the question was posted before, but with no useful answers:
[How to set header titles to wrap in QTableWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658464/how-to-set-header-titles-to-wrap-in-qtablewidget)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I decided to find a word wrapping algorithm that inserts new lines for dynamic input; not the best solution but easy

Answer (score 1):

I did it on this way (this method expects using the Qt Designer):

- throw a QTableWidget into your MainWindow or form
- double click the TableWidget
- enter your headings
- click the button "properties" in the bottom right corner
- adjust whatever you want

As far as I understood your question, this is the way I did it.
Hope it helped you and sorry for my bad english. :)

edit: try `tableWidget->setwordWrap(true)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not use the Qt Designer, only the Qt framework as GUI for my C++ application.
Any other suggestions? :)